# Create several variables into a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R.  I have several variables, for example, `country`, `customer ID`, etc.

After I use the read command CSV file, I notice that every row of the variables has to be list in order to create a data frame function?

```
country <- c("UK", "FR", "USA",etc) 

customer ID<- c(32133, 3428273,123437,etc)

age <-c(32, 10, 15, etc)
```

Is there a better way to create the data frame?

Comment: If there are only `vector` objects of same length in the global environment, use `ls` to find all the objects, then with `mget` return the values in a `list` and wrap it with `data.frame` i.e. `lst <- mget(ls());
 data.frame(lst[sapply(lst, is.vector)])`

Comment: Did you use `read.csv` or `read.table(FILE, sep=",")`?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Hi, I used e.g x1<-read.csv("Aprill.csv"). Does it mean that I do not need to create any data frame any more and use it straight away?